# DllImport not defined in asp.net code behind file even when including System.Runtime.InteropServices

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net

I would like to link to a C++ dll from my asp.net 3.5 web application and use some of the functions in the code behind.  If I create a C# library using DllImport to link to the C++ dll I can then link the C# library to the asp.net application and it seems to work.  How do I eliminate the C# library and link directly to the C++ dll?

When I try use DllImport in the C# code behind it is undefined even though the code looks identical to the code in the C# library.

code from the asp.net web app (doesn't work because DllImport gets highlighted as undefined)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Chat
/// </summary>
public class Chat
{
    public Chat()
    {
      [DllImport("ChatLib.dll")]
       public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to put `DllImport` attribute and method declaration out side constructor on class level.

```
public class Chat
{
    [DllImport("ChatLib.dll")]
    public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL();
    public Chat()
    {

    }        
}
```

Comment: Haha ok thanks.  I stared at this code for far too long and did not see that.  I guess it's nice when the answer is simple. :)